# ggplot2 move x-axis labels in facet panels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't really find an answer.

Data

```
subj <- c(rep(11,3),rep(12,3),rep(14,3),rep(15,3),rep(17,3),rep(18,3),rep(20,3))
group <- c(rep("u",3),rep("t",6),rep("u",6),rep("t",6))
time <- rep(1:3,7)
mean <- c(0.7352941, 0.8059701, 0.8823529, 0.9264706, 0.9852941, 0.9558824, 0.7941176, 0.8676471, 0.7910448, 0.7058824, 0.8382353, 0.7941176, 0.9411765, 0.9558824, 0.9852941, 0.7647059, 0.8088235, 0.7968750, 0.8088235, 0.8500000, 0.8412698)
df <- data.frame(subj,group,time,mean)
df$subj <- as.factor(df$subj)
df$time <- as.factor(df$time)
```

Here is the code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=subj, y=mean*100, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scale="free")
```

All I want is to display on the facet panels the x axis label number 12, 14, etc and they should be aligned just like they are on the x axis.

Otherwise I will have to move the x-axis on top and remove the panels.

Comment: You want the panel to become the axis? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @AndS. yes exactly

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, I clearly hadn't understood the question. I just did, after seeing the answer by @AndS. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I see what you are asking, and you could do it, however, it would be very arbitrary

```
library(tidyverse)

my_labs <- c(t = "12                14                18                20", 
             u = "11                      15                      17")
ggplot(df, aes(x=subj, y=mean*100, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scale="free", labeller = as_labeller(my_labs))
```

[image]

Instead, I recommend using `geom_text` to label the columns so that they always end up in the correct position. They will also look nicer in the long run.

```
my_text <- data_frame(subj = as.factor(c(12,14,18,20,11,15,17)), group = c(rep("t", 4), rep("u", 3)), mean = c(rep(105, 7)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=subj, y=mean*100, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_text(data = my_text, aes(x=subj, y=mean, label = subj), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~ group, scale="free")+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or if you are really looking for a second axis on top,

```
df <- df %>% mutate(subj = factor(subj, levels = c("12", "14", "18", "20", "11", "15", "17")))
my_labs <- levels(df$subj)
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.numeric(subj), y=mean*100, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scale="free")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:length(my_labs), labels = my_labs, sec.axis = dup_axis())+
  xlab("subj")+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-18 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: ok very interesting! Thank you. The second and third approach are definitely better. What is exactly geom_text?

Comment: `geom_text` is much like `geom_point`, except you are mapping a label instead of a shape or symbol (If that makes any sense). I find it particularly useful when I want to annotate graphs, add labels to bar charts, and/or sub-label facets in a faceted plot. Typically I make a separate dataframe for the labels, however, often times in heatmaps (geom_tile) or barcharts, you add the labels to the existing dataframe and map them out with no problem because the label is the data you are presenting..

Comment: In the second solution, you are remove the panels, but I would like to keep them. So you are not actually printing text inside them.

Comment: Do you just want a gray strip? You could achieve that with geom_rect or geom_polygon. I think option 2 is going to be your best bet